# Rollup by unique combinations

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am attempting to do a `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` function, and I am wanting to get back unique combinations based on the *values* of a field, rather than particular columns. Here's what I have so far.

With the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX responses_pkey ON responses(id int4_ops);

CREATE TABLE demographic_values (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX demographic_values_pkey ON demographic_values(id int4_ops);

CREATE TABLE response_demographics (
    response_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES responses(id),
    demographic_value_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES demographic_values(id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    response_id integer REFERENCES responses(id),
    question_id integer,
    rating integer
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX answers_pkey ON answers(id int4_ops);
```

And the following data inserted into this schema:

```
INSERT INTO public.responses VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO public.responses VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO public.responses VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO public.demographic_values VALUES (1, 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO public.demographic_values VALUES (2, 'SF');
INSERT INTO public.demographic_values VALUES (3, 'Male');
INSERT INTO public.demographic_values VALUES (4, 'Female');

INSERT INTO public.response_demographics VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO public.response_demographics VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO public.response_demographics VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO public.response_demographics VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO public.response_demographics VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO public.response_demographics VALUES (3, 3);

INSERT INTO public.answers VALUES (1, 1, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO public.answers VALUES (2, 1, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO public.answers VALUES (3, 1, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO public.answers VALUES (4, 2, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO public.answers VALUES (5, 3, 1, 1);
```

When I then run this query:

```
SELECT demographic_values.name, COUNT(answers.id) FROM answers 
INNER JOIN responses on responses.id = answers.response_id
INNER JOIN response_demographics on response_demographics.response_id = responses.id
INNER JOIN demographic_values on response_demographics.demographic_value_id = demographic_values.id
WHERE question_id = 1
GROUP BY ROLLUP(demographic_values.name)
```

I get back this data:

```
   name    | count
-----------+-------
           |     6
 Male      |     2
 SF        |     1
 Female    |     1
 Melbourne |     2
(5 rows)
```

What I would like to be returned instead is:

```
     column1     | column2
-----------------+---------
 Melbourne, Male |       1
 SF, Female      |       1
                 |       2
(3 rows)
```

Each count here is counting up each *unique demographic combination* of all the responses. If there was another response which had only the demographic of "Melbourne" but *not* "Male", then I would expect:

```
     column1     | column2
-----------------+---------
 Melbourne, Male |       1
 SF, Female      |       1
 Male            |       1
                 |       3
(4 rows)
```

How can I go about doing this `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` or, I guess `GROUPING SETS` on field values, rather than field names?

Even if it returned the demographic values as unique columns (as opposed to comma-separated strings) I would be fine with that.